# Numberformat exception for converting jtextfield to int

Tags: java, integer, numberformatexception, parseint

I've been looking at answers to other posts and they seem to point to what I'm doing, but I'm still getting `NumberFormatException`. I'm trying to build a simple calculator from a `JFrame` by pulling jtextfield value and converting it into int, but I'm getting the following exception.

```
package com.calculator.app;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class CalculatorApp extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    private JTextField textField_1 = new JTextField();
    private JTextField textField_2 = new JTextField();
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CalculatorApp frame = new CalculatorApp();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CalculatorApp() {

    //  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);    

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCalculatorApp = new JLabel("Calculator App");
        lblCalculatorApp.setBounds(141, 37, 138, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblCalculatorApp);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(74, 112, 131, 31);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(169, 181, 82, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(55, 73, 54, 23);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(151, 70, 54, 23);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(109, 162, 124, 55);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);
    //  textField_2.setText(String.valueOf(output));
        try{

            int output = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Error");    
                }

    }
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.calculator.ap.CalculatorApp.<init>(CalculatorApp.java:23)
    at com.calculator.ap.CalculatorApp$1.run(CalculatorApp.java:32)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: post the exception details but probably this`Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());` has the issue because this `extField.getText()` is not giving you right formatted integer

Comment: I posted exception above

Comment: You can't parse an empty string as a number, the string value must contain digits only for the parsing to be successful

Comment: follow the guidelines provided in the answer below , will solve the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```

is equivalent to

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt("");
```

because you don't initialize the `textField` with a specific value in this line:

```
private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
```

So, you are trying to parse an empty string as integer, but it throws `NumberFormatException`, because it's not an integer.

If you just want to get over those problems, you could put 3 integers there:

```
private JTextField textField = new JTextField("1");
private JTextField textField_1 = new JTextField("2");
private JTextField textField_2 = new JTextField("3");
```

or (much better) you can remove the following lines, because it seems that you need to parse them later (when the button is clicked):

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
```

---

The explanation above helps you to avoid that exception.

But if you want to sum those numbers, you should fill in the body of this method:

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String text1 = textField.getText();
            String text2 = textField_1.getText();
            textField_2.setText(getIntegerValue(text1) + getIntegerValue(text2) + "");
        }
    });
```

where `getIntegerValue` can look like this:

```
private int getIntegerValue(String s) {
    if ( "".equals(s) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

or shorter:

```
private int getIntegerValue(String s) {
    return "".equals(s) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

This method:

- returns `0` if the string is empty (no value)
- returns the integer if the string represents an integer
- throws `NumberFormatException` if the string is not an integer or an empty string
- doesn't need to catch `NumberFormatException`, because it's a `RuntimeException`

Of course, you can remove that `if` / ternary operator from the last method if you want to throw an exception even if the string is empty.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. So there isn't any built in methods that I can use without writing my own like you did with getIntegerValue to get this working?

Comment: I don't know another method. If you want to stop the exception for some inputs, I think that you should do this manually in pure Java (without external libraries). Now, depending on your needs, you could validate the input before (eventually using a regex).